# Topologies comparable?

Tags: general-topology

> **1)** I know that two topologies on $X$ may not be comparable. But, Munkres' Topology asks on P83:
>   Let $\{\cal T_{\alpha}\}$ be a family of topologies on $X$. Show that there is a unique smallest topology on $X$ containing all collections $\cal T_{\alpha}$, and a unique largest topology contained in all $\cal T_{\alpha}$.

My question regarding 1): How can we ask to find smallest or largest topology if they may be non-comaparable? For example, there may be two different topologies $\cal T$ and $\cal T'$ such that both are contained in all $\cal T_{\alpha}$, but non-comparable.

> **2)** How to prove this:
>   Let $\cal A$ be subset of power set $X$, and union of elements $\cal A$ need not be equal to $X$. So,  $\cal {A}\cup \{X\}$ forms subbasis for $X$. Prove that topology generated by $\cal {A}\cup \{X\}$ equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\cal {A}$.

Comment: Those smallest and largest topologies to be found are not required to be an element of the given collection. That is why it doesn't contradict the possible property of the given collection not being comparable topologies.

Comment: To get the largest contained in all look at the intersection of the given family of topologies. To get the smallest containing them, look at the collection of all topologies that contain them all. That collection is non-empty since the power set of $X$ contains them all and is a topology. Now find a minimum of that collection.

Comment: This seems to be about question 2: [The topology generated by a basis is the intersection of all topologies containing that basis.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/908528)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks, but I want to show that smallest topology containing a collection of subsets of X is equal to topology generated by subbasis formed by that collection with X.

Answer (score 1):

**To 1)**

Read "show that it is smaller" as "first show that it is comparable, than that it smaller" or "show that it is smaller, and hence that it must be comparable too". Just because two topologies $\mathcal T$ and $\mathcal T'$ are not comparable does not mean that there cannot be another topology $\mathcal T''$ which is comparable to both of them. Note that your desired "smallest" topology $\mathcal T$ does not have to be from the set $\{\mathcal T_\alpha\}$.

We could reformulate the problem statement in this way: Given a familiy $\{\mathcal T_\alpha\}$ of topologies, show that there is a topology $\mathcal T$ which

- is is comparable to all topologies in $\{\mathcal T_\alpha\}$,
- contains any topology in $\{\mathcal T_\alpha\}$, i.e. is larger than any of them,
- is comparable to any other topology with the same properties, and
- is also smaller than (or equal to) any other topology with the same properties, i.e. is the unique smallest one of them.

Of course it could be that no such topology exists, but the way in which the problem is stated suggests the opposite. By the way, it is not hard to find that $\mathcal T=\bigcup \mathcal T_\alpha$.